# Quantify significance between measured value and prediction (with error)?

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-error, measurement-error

I have a question about the proper way to describe the results I get to a prediction (both of which have statistical errors). I get a result with 1-sigma, let's say:

```
-1 +/- 2
```

There is a published prediction (and 1-sigma error) for this measured value, let's say:

```
4 +/- 1.5.
```

If there is a precise way of describing my result? I mean, should I say, "this is consistent within 2-sigma?" or "it's inconsistent... sorta"?

**I would like to be able to quantify the significance of the disagreement (or agreement) between the measurement and the prediction.**

If it's easier to use variables instead of numbers, let's use my result is a +/- b; predicted value: x +/- y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided what I'm going to do with this problem -- if you have a more clever idea, please let me know.

Add the two statistical errors in quadrature and quantify the difference between them in units of that new, larger error.

```
Measured: a +/- b
predicted value: x +/- y

total_sigma = sqrt(b^2 + y^2)
```

Deviations away ~ abs(x - a) / total_sigma.